# Intuition for Fano visitors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

I have a hopefully simple question regarding derived categories of projective varieties. A question of Bondal asks if $Y$ is a smooth projective variety, is there a smooth projective Fano variety $X$ such that there is a fully faithful embedding $D^b(Y) \to D^b(X)$ (presumably as an admissible subcategory). To my knowledge, thanks to Kuznetsov's HPD and work on the derived categories of cubic fourfolds there has been a lot of attention on several special cases of this.

I am curious why we restrict out attention to just Fano $X$? Is there some reason why we would expect the answer to be no in the case where $X$ is CY or general type?

Comment: Calabi-Yau varieties have indecomposable derived categories, so they are out of the question. Fano varieties always have a decomposition, as $\mathcal{O}_X$ is always an exceptional object. There are varieties of general type for which the same is true, but it is "rare" in some sense, see also Kawatani--Okawa's indecomposability result.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation.